# node-oracledb multiple statement in one query

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, node-oracledb, node-mysql2

In MySQL we can do the multiple statement in one query like below example. Is there any similar way to run multiple statement in one query in oracledb?

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    multipleStatements: true
})

app.get('/distinct',(req,res)=>{  
    connection.query('select DISTINCT country FROM sample_data.olympic_winners order by country ASC; select DISTINCT sport FROM sample_data.olympic_winners order by sport ASC',(err,rows)=>{  
    if(!err)   
    res.send(rows);  
    else  
        console.log(err);  
      
})  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle only lets you execute one SQL or PL/SQL statement at a time.

You could wrap your queries in a PL/SQL block and use Oracle's Implicit Result Sets, see the [doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#implicitresults):

For example:

```
const plsql = `
  DECLARE
    c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
    c2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT city, postal_code
                FROM locations
                WHERE location_id < 1200;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);

    OPEN C2 FOR SELECT job_id, employee_id, last_name
                FROM employees
                WHERE employee_id < 103;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c2);
  END;`;

result = await connection.execute(plsql);
console.log(result.implicitResults);
```

will display:

```
[
  [
    [ 'Roma', '00989' ],
    [ 'Venice', '10934' ],
  ],
  [
    [ 'AD_PRES', 100, 'King' ],
    [ 'AD_VP', 101, 'Kochhar' ],
    [ 'AD_VP', 102, 'De Haan' ],
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to unite the queries on the database side in a single select statement without invocation of PL/SQL:

```
select DISTINCT 'country', country FROM sample_data.olympic_winners 
  UNION ALL
select DISTINCT 'sport', sport FROM sample_data.olympic_winners
  order by 1,2 ASC;
```

This approach requires identical row structures of the involved tables and delivers a compound resultset. It depends on what is the goal to be achieved with such a compound request, like the required structure of the resultset (just a plain unified list or rather hierarchical master-detail).